# ggplot x axis for year

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, axis-labels

The following are my `r code` for the scatterplot.

```
library(tidyverse)
Pop <-c(24039274, 24854892, 25718048, 26624820, 27568436, 28543940, 29550662, 30590487, 31663896, 32771895)
Popu <- data.frame(Year = 2000:2009, lpop = log2(Pop))
ggplot(Popu, aes(Year, lpop)) + 
  geom_point(size=3, col = "steelblue") +
  ylab("Log2 of Population")
```

[image]

My question is, why the x axis reflects 2000.0, 2002.5 and so on? How do I fix this one?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Popu <- data.frame(Year = factor(seq(2000,2009,1)), lpop = log2(Pop))
ggplot(Popu, aes(Year, lpop)) + 
geom_point(size=3, col = "steelblue") +
ylab("Log2 of Population")
```

Comment: Is there some way to decrease the number of x axis ticks in ggplot2?

Comment: We can use `scale_x_discrete(breaks = pretty(Popu$Year, n = 5))`